# MS Access SQL Query - Error in Join

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

i am new to SQL and have been trying to have an SQL query in MS Access to join multiple tables using the below sql.  This is for doing access testing.

Have explained what i intent to achieve in **bold**

```
SELECT

Table1.Role,
Table1.Object,
```

**Table 1 is the base table which has role, authorization object**

```
Table2.Role,
Table2.User_Name,
```

**Table 2 has the users mapped to the role**

```
Table3.Org_Level_Desp,
Table3.Org_LEvel_Values_1,
```

**Table 3 has controls at organization level, this determine which company or plant the user can access**

```
Table4.Role_Description,
```

**Table 4 has role descriptions for roles mentioned in Table 1**

```
Table5.Full_Name,
Table5.Department,
```

**Table 5 has user name and department.  Common field is user name from table 2**

```
FROM
Table1
RIGHT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Role=Table2.Role
RIGHT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.Role=Table3.Role
RIGHT JOIN Table4 ON Table1.Role=Table4.rOLE
```

**Joining required tabled from Table 2, 3 and 4 to Table 1**

```
FROM 
Table2
RIGHT JOIN Table5 ON Table2.USER_NAME=Table5.USer
```

**Joining required tables from table 5 to table 1**

I am getting multiple syntax error for the above query.  I think i am missing on something basic - Can anyone help ?

Thanks !
Uday

---

Seems i cannot add more in comment.  Sorry, below is the code that i updated, still getting the same error.  Can you please advise ?

```
SELECT

TABLE1.Role, 
TABLE1.Object, 
TABLE1.Field_name, 
TABLE1.Value, 
TABLE1.[and], 
TABLE1.ID_whether_object_is_deleted, 

TABLE2.Role,
TABLE2.User_Name,
TABLE2.End_date,

TABLE3.Org_Level_Control,
TABLE3.Org_LEvel_Values_1,
TABLE3.Org_LEvel_Values_2,

Table4.Role_Description,

TABLE6.Field_Short_Description,

TABLE7.Object_Level_Desp,

TABLE8.Auth_Obj_Text,

TABLE5.Full_Name,
TABLE5.Department,

TABLE9.Valid_to,
TABLE9.Lock,

from ((((((TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.Role=TABLE2.Role)
INNER JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE1.Role=TABLE3.Role)
INNER JOIN Table4 ON TABLE1.Role=Table4.role)
INNER JOIN TABLE6 ON TABLE1.Field_Name=TABLE6.Field_Name)
INNER JOIN TABLE7 ON TABLE1.[Object]=TABLE7.Org_Object)
INNER JOIN TABLE8 ON AGR_TABLE1.Field_name=TABLE8.Field_Name)

FROM 
(TABLE2 INNER JOIN TABLE5 ON TABLE2.USER_NAME=TABLE5.[USer])
INNER JOIN TABLE9 ON TABLE2.USER_NAME=TABLE9.[User]);
```

---

Below is the code that i updated, still getting the same error. Can you please advise ?

```
SELECT

TABLE1.Role, 
TABLE1.Object, 
TABLE1.Field_name, 
TABLE1.Value, 
TABLE1.[and], 
TABLE1.ID_whether_object_is_deleted, 

TABLE2.Role,
TABLE2.User_Name,
TABLE2.End_date,

TABLE3.Org_Level_Control,
TABLE3.Org_LEvel_Values_1,
TABLE3.Org_LEvel_Values_2,

Table4.Role_Description,

TABLE6.Field_Short_Description,

TABLE7.Object_Level_Desp,

TABLE8.Auth_Obj_Text,

TABLE5.Full_Name,
TABLE5.Department,

TABLE9.Valid_to,
TABLE9.Lock,

from ((((((TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.Role=TABLE2.Role)
INNER JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE1.Role=TABLE3.Role)
INNER JOIN Table4 ON TABLE1.Role=Table4.role)
INNER JOIN TABLE6 ON TABLE1.Field_Name=TABLE6.Field_Name)
INNER JOIN TABLE7 ON TABLE1.[Object]=TABLE7.Org_Object)
INNER JOIN TABLE8 ON AGR_TABLE1.Field_name=TABLE8.Field_Name)
```

Comment: You can't have multiple "FROM" statements. To follow your logic above, under your join to "Table4", try RIGHT JOIN Table5 ON Table2.UserName =Table5.User

Comment: By the way, you need to stick a colon on the end of the query if you are using MS Access.

Comment: you have tagged ms-access, try creating the tables and use the graphical query designer to generate your query.

Comment: @DavyC: you probably meant a semicolon `;`, but you don't actually need this. Access appends it when using the query designer, but it's optional.

Comment: Yeah, typo, and I didn't know that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you would want `RIGHT JOIN`, particularly if you are learning SQL.  Start with `INNER JOIN`.  If that is leaving out rows, then move to `LEFT JOIN`.

The syntax in MS Access uses parentheses:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM (((Table1 INNER JOIN
        Table2
        ON Table1.Role = Table2.Role
       ) INNER JOIN
       Table3
       ON Table1.Role = Table3.Role
      ) INNER JOIN
      Table4
      ON Table1.Role = Table4.rOLE
     ) INNER JOIN
     Table5
     ON Table2.USER_NAME = Table5.USer
```

You can then select the columns you want in the `SELECT`.

Note that the parentheses would look quite awkward in any other database.

Comment: Thank you.. Appreciate your time for responding to the query.  I will try our inner join and see how it works.  When i tried the above query, it says "The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect"  Can you please advise where i am going wrong ?

Comment: @UdayKumar . . . `user` is a reserved word.  You should probably name the column something else or put it in square braces.

Answer (score 1):

Re: your updated SQL.

`Value` is a [reserved word in Access SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875%28v=office.12%29.aspx), so may be others like `Role, Object, Lock`. Put these into [square brackets], both in the SELECT and the FROM clause.

And you have an extraneous comma at the end of your SELECT clause:

```
TABLE9.Valid_to,
TABLE9.Lock,    <== delete this comma

from ((((((TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.Role=TABLE2.Role)
```